# OpenMP Code Not Scaling due to overheads and cache issues

Tags: windows, caching, matrix, openmp, scaling

```c
struct xnode
{
  float *mat;
};

void testScaling( )
{
  int N = 1000000; ///total num matrices
  int dim = 10;

  //memory for matrices
  std::vector<xnode> nodeArray(N);
  for( int k = 0; k < N; ++k )
    nodeArray[k].mat = new float [dim*dim];

  //memory for Y
  std::vector<float*> Y(N,0);
  for( int k = 0; k < N; ++k )
    Y[k] = new float [dim];

  //shared X
  float* X = new float [dim];
  for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i ) X[i] = 1.0;

  //init mats
  for( int k = 0; k < N; ++k )
  {
    for( int i=0; i<dim*dim; ++i )
      nodeArray[k].mat[i] = 0.25+((float)i)/3;
  }

  int NTIMES = 500;
  //gemv args
  char trans = 'N';
  int lda = dim;
  int incx = 1;
  float alpha =1 , beta = 0;  

  //threads
  int thr[4];
  thr[0] =1 ; thr[1] = 2; thr[2] = 4; thr[3] = 8;

  for( int t = 0; t<4; ++t )//test for nthreads
  {
    int nthreads = thr[t];
    double t_1 = omp_get_wtime();
    for( int ii = 0; ii < NTIMES; ++ii )//do matvec NTIMES
    {
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads)
      for( int k=0; k<N; ++k )
      {
        //compute Y[k] = mat[k] * X;
        GEMV(&trans, &dim, &dim, &alpha, nodeArray[k].mat, &lda, X, &incx, &beta, Y[k], &incx);           
        //GEMV(&trans, &dim, &dim, &alpha, nodeArray[0].mat, &lda, X, &incx, &beta, Y[k], &incx);           
      }
    }
    double t_2 = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout << "Threads " << nthreads << " time " << (t_2-t_1)/NTIMES << std::endl;
  }

  //clear memory
  for( int k = 0; k < N; ++k )
  {
    delete [] nodeArray[k].mat;
    delete [] Y[k];
  }
  delete [] X;
}
```

The above code parallelizes the matrix-vector product of N matrices of size dim, and stores results in N output vectors. The average of 500 products is taken as the time per matrix-vector product. The matrix-vector products in the above example are all of equal size and thus the threads should be perfectly balanced - we should achieve a performance scaling close to ideal 8x. The following are the observations (Machine – Intel Xeon 3.1Ghz.2 processors,8cores each, HyperThreading enabled, Windows, VS2012, Intel MKL, Intel OMP library).

## OBSERVATION  1:

dim=10 N=1000000 
Threads 1 - time 0.138068s 
Threads 2 - time 0.0729147s 
Threads 4 - time 0.0360527s 
Threads 8 - time 0.0224268s (6.1x on 8threads)

## OBSERVATION 2 :

dim=20 N=1000000 
Threads 1 time 0.326617 
Threads 2 time 0.185706 
Threads 4 time 0.0886508 
Threads 8 time 0.0733666 (4.5x on 8 threads).
Note – I ran VTune on this case. It showed CPUTime 267.8sec, Overhead time 43 sec, Spin time – 8 sec. The overhead time is all spent in a libiomp function (intel library). 8Threads/1Thread scaling is poor for such cases.

Next - in the gemv for loop, we change nodeArray[k].mat to nodeArray[0].mat (see commented statement), so that only the first matrix is used for all the matrix-vector products.

## OBSERVATION 3

dim=20 N=1000000 
Threads 1 time 0.152298 (The serial time is halved) 
Threads 2 time 0.0769173 
Threads 4 time 0.0384086 
Threads 8 time 0.019336 (7.87x on 8 threads)

Thus I get almost ideal scaling - why is this behavior? VTune says that a significant portion of CPU time is spent in synchronization and thread overhead. Here it seems there is no relation between the load balancing and thread synchronization.  As matrix size is increased the granularity should increase and thread overhead should be proportionately small. But as we increase from size 10 to 20 the scaling is weakening. When we use nodeArray[0].mat (only the first matrix) for doing all the matrix-vector products the cache is updated only once (since the compiler knows this during optimization) and we get near ideal scaling. Thus the synchronization overhead seems to be related to some cache related issue. I have tried a number of other things like setting KMP_AFFINITY and varying load distribution but that did not buy me anything.

My questions are: 
1. I dont have a clear idea about how does the cache performance affect openMP thread synchronization. Can someone explain this? 
2. Can anything be done about improving the scaling and reducing the overhead?

Thanks

Comment: Any new information on this in the meantime?